# How do I get the author of an article using python-goose

Tags: python, web-scraping, goose

I'm trying to scrape articles from news agencies, but I can't figure out how to get the author of an article using python-goose. I've read through the documentation, source code and searched google.

```
from goose import Goose

def getArticle(url):
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    print article.title
    # print article.author
    # print article.writer
```

So, is there a built in way to extract the author of an article using python-goose?

Link for python-goose code and documenation: http://github.com/grangier/python-goose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [their documentation](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/blob/develop/README.rst):

> Goose will try to extract the following information:
>
> - Main text of an article
> - Main image of article
> - Any Youtube/Vimeo movies embedded in article
> - Meta Description
> - Meta tags

They don't promise to get the author; you will need to look into the metadata to see if it's included and extract it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Newspaper may satisfy your requirements.

Here is the usage:>>> article.authors
[u'Leigh Ann Caldwell', 'John Honway']

You can find more details from its document or Github.
http://newspaper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It is quite simple and powerful.